# How to find absolute path of uploaded image - Django 1.11

Tags: django, file-io, django-forms, django-views

I have a django form in which the user can upload an image that will then be displayed on a page. After the form request is submitted, I'm trying to return an httpresponse to the user of the uploaded image using the following code:

```
image_data = open("/path/to/my/image.png", "rb").read()
return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image/png")
```

The issue is that I can't get the absolute path from image submitted in the form request. By doing the following, I can get the name of the image, but not the local path to it:

```
name = ""
for filename, file in request.FILES.iteritems():
    name = request.FILES[filename]      
    imageFileName = name
```

I've tried using the function `file_to_string()` based on an SO post, but it looks like the function is deprecated now. **How can I get the absolute file path so I can pass it to the open function to return the image?**

**models.py**

```
class PhotoUploader(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length =120)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Comment: did use models for that ??

Comment: @Robert Yes, I included in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solutions:

once you save the image,then you may got the path like that:

```
instance = PhotoUploader.objects.get(id=instance_id);
image_full_path = instance.image.path
image_data = open(image_full_path, "rb").read()
return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image/png")
```

"image_full_path" this should be your uploaded image full path.

Comment: Where is `instance_id` defined?

Comment: after save data,you get last instance id of "PhotoUploader".this will be instance id